# Why can't I see photos from my Nikon camera after upgrading to Windows 10?

Tags: nikon, windows, file-transfer, windows-10

I had recently upgraded to windows 10 and now Windows and Lightroom don't "see" the photos on my D5100. I am able to transfer them to the PC through viewNX but this is not a pleasant solution.

When I go to the folder where the photos should be while using Windows Exploror, the folder is void even if the card is shown to have a certain space full. When I right click and try to do "import photos and videos" it just says no photos to import, same stuff in lightroom. NX works fine. How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess you are missing some driver. Don't know which since I don't use windows 10

Comment: might be far fetched but have you checked if hidden files are shown ? (in any folder click View top right then options and then select view tab)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with my Nikon D5100 DSLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed in one of the recent (this week)'s windows updates. Just do a Windows Update, restart your PC as prompted to ensure installation, and try again. You will see that the issue has now gone away.

---

Many people, including me,  are reporting this problem. See [Window 10 and Nikon D7000 dslr](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/window-10-and-nikon-d7000-dslr/c2b5b7d2-ce67-4ac3-97c7-57e49236c5bb) on Microsoft's support forum.

It appears to be a problem with the  MTP protocol implementation in this build of Win 10. As you note Nikon's own software products work fine.

On July 31, 2015, a Microsoft representative noted:

> This is a known issue and we are rapidly working on a fix.