# Windows 10 can't see pictures from Nikon Coolpix S6300

Tags: nikon, windows-10

I just upgraded to Windows 10 and now I can't seem to download my pictures to my computer.   I downloaded the device so it's recognizing it but when I go to the action center it says to tap to decide what to do with the device but when I tap it, it goes away and doesn't do anything.  It's sounding like I might need a patch to be compatible, please Help

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66009/why-cant-i-see-photos-from-my-nikon-camera-after-upgrading-to-windows-10

Comment: actually, maybe this isn't a duplicate of that question/problem/solution.

Comment: Please title your question in a way that helps explain the question. Thanks.

Comment: These types of questions I find to be the least interesting of all of the questions this site has. Maybe superuser would be better anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have latest version of firmware if the issue remains there ask Microsoft about the issue 
http://nikonasia-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7842/~/nikon-coolpix-s6300-firmware-ver.-1.1-download