# Why can't I download pictures from my camera with Windows 10 64bit?

Tags: canon, file-transfer, windows-10

My PC starts to download pictures, indicates the correct number of pictures in the camera and then the display on the camera blanks, and then the computer reports that no pictures exist. Windows 7 works OK, and taking the SD card and plugging it into my Epson WorkForce 840 works OK as well.

Comment: related - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/nikon-coolpix-s6300 and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66009/why-cant-i-see-photos-from-my-nikon-camera-after-upgrading-to-windows-10

Comment: Fred, Win10 is very new and drivers just not compatible with everything yet.  Have you tried a card reader, rather than plugging in the camera?

Comment: I was kicking myself when I upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 because I found that Nikon had made it clear that they would never provide Windows 7 drivers for my [Nikon Coolscan V ED](http://www.bobulous.org.uk/imho/Nikon_Coolscan-V-ED.html) slide/negative scanner, so the (perfectly good) Nikon software which comes with it would no longer work. (I know there are commercial software alternatives, but it was still a nuisance.) In short: be very careful to check your hardware and software requirements before you upgrade your operating system.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about RAW data. Please make sure that you have the latest firmware installed in your camera and that you have the correct decoders installed in Windows

Comment: What is the name of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 10.  I have never used the Picture Import utility.  I eject SD cards from the camera and copy and paste them manually where I want them to go 1st) to local drive preferred and 2nd to external hard drive.

As I do not work from cards.  As soon as the copy routine is done, I eject the card.

I use Adobe Lightroom and when I am done exporting images out of Lightroom they get copied over to the external hard drive as well.

Comment: My workflow is basically the same, though I've never owned a computer with any of those Windows versions. I'm also using Lightroom and I copy the files manually from my SD card rather than using any import utility.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with CP780  and windows 10. Youtube video suggested the use of the Vista drivers downloaded from the canon usa site. Works a charm also used the Selphy print utility also listed for vista.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Import option on Windows once it acknowledged the device? It ususally works.

Also you can pop out the memory card and use your card reader if your machine has one. If not, then turn off the camera and see if Windows can detect the memory card.

**Make sure the device has its drivers installed.**

Answer (score 0):

While it may be a driver issue, it could also be an electrical issue.  If I leave my D7100 attached to the USB cable on my Mac, the mac will drain the battery in about 2 hours.  Why it should do so is beyond me.

Worth changing cable.  Worth verifying on a different computer running windows 10.